# How to Pass data from database to Google Chart

Tags: mysql, html, servlets, google-visualization

Suppose I am going to generate this chart http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.html

And i am willing to read the data from Mysql database and pass it to

```
data.addRows([
          ['2004', 1000, 400],
          ['2005', 1170, 460],
          ['2006', 660, 1120],
          ['2007', 1030, 540]
        ]);
```

to replace the hardcoded data and display the chart. The servlet file is in HTML format.
How can I do so?? Many thanks I get stuck here for a long time

Comment: Can anyone help? I have searching for google for a long time.
All of them are using php to connect mysql.
Can i do so without using PHP

Comment: You don't have to use PHP, but you need something for server-side coding. Html alone won't get you access to the database.

Comment: see this question/answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219282/how-to-get-mysql-data-into-a-google-chart-using-php-loop

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `Ajax` to point to a php file which parses the data to a `JSON` file and read it.

More info can be found here: [Google Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)